# Any plugin for Xamarin.Forms / Xamarin.Android for selecting directory to save file?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Any plugin/control available for Xamarin.Forms / Xamarin.Android for selecting the directory to save file? Basically, I need to allow the user to browse location where they want to save file.

I am aware there is a control available file picker. But it allows to pick a file doesn't provide an option to choose a location for saving file. I need a similar control which allows selecting file location to save.

Comment: you would probably need to modify the existing file picker to support this.  I'm sure they would appreciate a PR if you add this feature

Answer (score -1):

I have used **Xam.Plugin.FilePicker** it working perfect. Check below points to implement.

1.Install into your PCL project and Client projects.

```
Install-Package Install-Package Xam.Plugin.FilePicker
```

2. Call CrossFilePicker.Current from any project or PCL to gain access to APIs.

   fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();

3.Android: The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are required.

4. iOS: Need Configure iCloud Driver for your app

Comment: I am aware of this already, as I mentioned in the question, my requirement is to pick directory location and not file for save purpose,